# Hadoop Pig count number

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am learning how to use Hadoop Pig now.

If I have a input file like this:

```
a,b,c,true
s,c,v,false
a,s,b,true
...
```

The last field is the one I need to count... So I want to know how many 'true' and 'false' in this file.

I try:

```
records = LOAD 'test/input.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
boolean = foreach records generate $3;
groups = group boolean all;
```

Now I gets stuck. I want to use:

```
count = foreach groups generate count('true');"
```

To get the number of "true" but I always get the error:

> 2013-08-07 16:32:36,677 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>       Details at logfile: /etc/pig/pig_1375911119028.log

Can anybody tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things.  Firstly, `count` should actually be [`COUNT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#count).  In pig, all builtin functions should be called with all-caps.

Secondly, `COUNT` counts the number of values in a bag, not for a value.  Therefore, you should group by true/false, then `COUNT`:

```
boolean = FOREACH records GENERATE $3 AS trueORfalse ;
groups = GROUP boolean BY trueORfalse ;
counts = FOREACH groups GENERATE group AS trueORfalse, COUNT(boolean) ;
```

So now the output of a `DUMP` for `counts` will look something like:

```
(true, 2)
(false, 1)
```

If you want the counts of true and false in their own relations then you can [`FILTER`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#filter) the output of `counts`.  However, it would probably be better to [`SPLIT`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#SPLIT) `boolean`, then do two separate counts:

```
boolean = FOREACH records GENERATE $3 AS trueORfalse ;
SPLIT boolean INTO alltrue IF trueORfalse == 'true', 
                   allfalse IF trueORfalse == 'false' ;

tcount = FOREACH (GROUP alltrue ALL) GENERATE COUNT(alltrue) ;
fcount = FOREACH (GROUP allfalse ALL) GENERATE COUNT(allfalse) ;
```